# linq2sql, repository pattern - how to query data from two or more tables?

Tags: performance, linq-to-sql, architecture, repository-pattern

I use Repository pattern (and linq2sql as data access) and have, for example, ProductsRep and CustomersRep.

In very simple scenario db has two tables -  *Produsts* (ProductID, CustomerID, ProductName, Date) and  *Customer* (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName).

Each repository provide methods to create, update, delete and get specific model object, and, may be, some filters.

But if I want to query all customers that buy specific product by product name, I have to get ProductID of this product using ProductsRep and then get all customers that buy product with this id using CustomersRep.

Am I right? This is actually two sql requests that l2s must generate, is it possible to do only one request?

And, in general, if we want to query data using multiple tables with relationships and repository pattern, how to do this by reduce amount of queries to minimum?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you could sketch out your tables. Name and columns. And please use some line breaks in your text.

Comment: You should not group your repositories (if you should group them at all) by tables, but by usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the statement you made:

> But if I want to query all customers
>   that buy specific product by product
>   name, I have to get ProductID of this
>   product using ProductsRep and then get
>   all customers that buy product with
>   this id using CustomersRep.

That smells trouble. **Create a repository to facilitate behaviour in a isolated area of your domain, not for each business entity.**

A common mistake with DDD/Repository is to think about data. DONT. Think about behaviour.

You have a **Products** entity which refers to a **Customer**. Which means a Product cannot exist without a customer. Right? Therefore a **Customer** is your aggregate root - it controls the behaviour of this portion of your domain model.

Your comment to the answer above confirms that - you are working across multiple repositories. You have two options - 1) unit of work, 2) fix up your repository design.

You only need 1 Repository - let's call it **CustomerProductRepository**.

Then to do your above query:

```
var customersWhoBuyHats = customerProductRepository
                             .Products
                             .Include("Customer")
                             .Where(x => x.ProductName == "Hat")
                             .Select(x => x.Customer)
                             .ToList();
```

The result is a **`List<Customer>`**, and you did it with one database call.

HTH.

Comment: My bad - forgot you were using L2SQL. `Include` is EF. The equivalent in L2SQL is `DataLoadOptions`. You get the jist of my answer though (i hope). And another point - Repository w/ IQueryable's really isn't suited for L2SQL. If you want to get this DDD'ey, then you should consider moving to Entity Framework.

Comment: I found two others solutions, which can be rather good. 1) we use one instance of DataContext for all repositories, so we can manipulate with IQueryable without any exception. 2) to retrieve data from multiple tables we use views in db, that mapped to classes using L2S and repositories are only for CRUD. What about this approaches? And why Repository with IQueryable's really isn't suited for L2SQL?

Comment: You should use approach 1. I have no idea why you would want multiple data contexts, unless you have databases on different machines. Pass the DataContext to the ctor of the Repository, that way all repositories can use the same DC.

Comment: And regarding my statement about Repository/IQueryable with L2SQL - L2SQL does not support POCO mapping for tables. Which means your IQueryable/Repository is returning actual table entities to your lower layers. Unless you project them into a POCO manually, but then how do you save this entity? You need left-to-right property copying to translate the POCO to the L2SQL entity. Either way, your Repository becomes too complicated, and not serving it's purpose. EF supports POCO out of the box, makes it very easy for abstraction.

Comment: Now I use approach you described - my repositories returned POCO objects, that translated to L2SQL entities and vice versa, it rather complicate, yes. I am convinced that I should start learning EF sooner or later.

Comment: @Kai - absolutely. L2SQL is basically obsolete - no more updates are planned. EF on the other hand is maturing nicely and has great support from the .NET community.

Answer (score 0):

```
var customers = from cust in CustomersRep
                join prod in ProductsRep on prod.CustomerID equals cust.CustomerID
                where prod.ProductName == yourInput
                select cust;
```

You can write a query, similar to you would in SQL (essentially). In the above `yourInput` is the variable that holds the product name you're interested in.

This should give you a single DB query request, so long as ProductsRep and CustomersRep are in the same DB.

Comment: If in our CustomersRep and ProductsRep there is a method GetAll() that returns IQueryable<T> of all entities, and we use your approach we instantly get the exception "The query contains references to items defined on a different data context.", because repositories are referenced to different datacontexts

Comment: What do you gain by having your tables in two different contexts?

Comment: I try to implement Repository pattern, where every repository create it's own datacontext, and now I understand that is not good idea for some scenarios...